# AngularJS : Detect if model has changed

Tags: angularjs

I have a tree view.  A user can select a node, then edit configuration of that node.  I would like a way to detect whether this has changed at all from the original.

All examples I've seen of `$watch` happens on a scope level and don't allow me to see when a model has changed.  How can I setup a watch (or something similar) that will tell me which object was changed so that I can do something like

```
$scope.itemChanged = function(item) {
  item.hasChanged = angular.equals(item, item.original);
}
```

I have tried deep watch examples like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15424144/94278) but they tell me only that the entire tree has changed, rather than which node. e.g.

```
$scope.$watch('tree', function (oldValue, newValue, scope) {
    console.log("changed", oldValue, newValue, scope);
}, true);
```

Comment: have you considered binding a change on the inputs the user can manipulate?

Comment: @Sphaso That was my first thought, but I also allow users to add nodes and to move nodes which would happen outside of the "form" so ideally I'd like to monitor all changes

Comment: What would you like to do once a node changes \ gets added etc.?

Comment: You can do watch a function `$watch(function(){ return changedNode }, function(newVal){ })`, but I would recommend capturing the changes in `ng-change` of inputs, rather than with a deep-watch

Answer (score 1):

I have not done much angularjs but your question intrigued me so I think this post may help you [angularjs treeview](http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/). The example has what I think you're looking for because it returns the .selectNodeHead that you can manipulate.

```
&(c.angularTreeview?(a.$watch(e,function(m,b){g.empty().html($compile(k)(a))},!1),a.selectNodeHead=a.selectNodeHead||function(a,b){b.stopPropagation&&b.stopPropagation()
```

Keep coding. Cheers