# How to watch for a model's deep changes, from templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a model on my scope, which is an object of objects. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423927/angular-js-automatically-detect-change-in-model), but I want to do this from the template as I have a filter defined on it.

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);

App.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.items = {
    { name: 'Cricket bat', cost: '2500', quantity: 0},
    { name: 'Football', cost: '1100', quantity: 0}
};
$scope.cartItems = {};  // This holds the items. I want quantity of each item separately so it's not an array.
```

I have defined a filter `getPrice` which calculates the price for the items in users cart.

And I have in the template:

```
{{ cartItems | getPrice }}
```

Is it possible to have the template update after any of the nested object value (ie. quantity of one of the items from the cart) changes? If yes, how?

Comment: If `cartItems` changes, the template will change also. What is the problem?

Comment: can you show your template?

Answer (score 0):

Move the quantity field to the cartItem object

```
$scope.items = {
    { name: 'Cricket bat', cost: '2500'},
    { name: 'Football', cost: '1100'}
};

$scope.cartItems = {
    { name: 'Cricket bat', quantity: 3},
    { name: 'Football', quantity: 6}
};
```

Then update your getprice filter based on the above json. This should take care of your cost in the cart getting updated when a price of an item changes.

Comment: In my template I am iterating over items to show them. They have checkbox (model: item.isSelected) and a number input (model: item.quantity). This means I have to keep duplicated info for quantity in both items and cartItems.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your strategy is not good overall.

1. An "*object of objects*" as you mean it `{ {id:1}, {id:2} }` is just not valid javascript, and will generate an error. Choose an array of objects `[ {id:1}, {id:2} ]` or a true object `{ 1: {id:1}, 2: {id:2} }`
2. @Blackhole is right, you don't need to watch anything, **interpolation** is part of angular.js core and does all that tricky *watch* stuff for you. Defining a `cartItems` variable, and interpoling it (with brackets `{}`) in a template, filtering it or not, will keep the interpolated value in sync with the variable value without you doing anything more. It's even two-ways bound (if you change model, variable will also change). You can verify the sync by removing temporiraly your filter : try to put `{cartItems}` in your template and update your cart, you'll see the template updated.
3. This model format would probably be more appropriate

   ```
   $scope.items = [
       { name: 'Cricket bat', cost: '2500' },
       { name: 'Football', cost: '1100' }
   ];

   $scope.cartItems = [
       { item: { name: 'Cricket bat', cost: '2500' }, quantity: 3 },
   ];
   ```